# Is it possible to "watch" Vuex module?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have single module imported in to the `Vuex` store:

```
import date from './modules/date-select';

export default new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {date},
});
```

Is it possible somehow to "watch" in component for whole module change? Something like:

```
import { mapState  } from 'vuex';

export default {
    computed: {
        ...mapState(['date'])
    },

    watch: {
        'date': function(date) {
            console.log(date)
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine like when i try to watch specific property of module like `date.timeframe` or `date.interval` but I need to perform actions when changing any parameter

Answer (score 2):

It should be with deep flag. For example:

```
watch: {

    people: {
          handler: function (val, oldVal) {
            // Return the object that changed
            var changed = val.filter( function( p, idx ) {
              return Object.keys(p).some( function( prop ) {
                return p[prop] !== oldVal[idx][prop];
              })
            })
            // Log it
            console.log(changed)
          },
          deep: true
        }
}
```